# Do I have to free/destroy ArrayAdapters in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, lifecycle

Do I have to free my custom ArrayAdapters in fragments, like I do it with binding? And also what about `ArrayList` that holds the data?

Inside my `Fragment` class I have:

```
private var binding: FragmentUhfReadBinding? = null            // init onCreateView, free onDestroyView, use onViewCreated
private var listAdapter: ReadUhfTagInfoItemViewAdapter? = null // init in onViewCreated
private val arrayList: ArrayList<ReadUhfTagInfo?>? = ArrayList()

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater,
                          container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    binding = FragmentUhfReadBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    return binding!!.root
}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    binding = null
    // do I have to set `listAdapter` to null here?
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    listAdapter = ReadUhfTagInfoItemViewAdapter(this.context, arrayList)

    binding!!.lvData.adapter = listAdapter
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because your adapter is referencing a context (which is the attached Activity).

It's also referencing a list that you have created only in your Fragment, but it's debatable whether you should care if that's leaked. It would be more typical for backing list data to be in a ViewModel so it could be reused, in which case this list reference your adapter is holding wouldn't be a problem.

Although your example doesn't show it, it's also very common for an adapter to expose some kind of listener for view interactions. So when you add this, and your listeners capture references to other stuff in the fragment, then the adapter would also be leaking the memory of those things.

---

However, it is not common in the first place to need your binding and your adapter to be in class properties. If you use them solely within `onViewCreated()` and functions called by `onViewCreated()`, then you don't need to worry about clearing references to them, and you won't have the ugly use of `!!`, so it will be more robust.

Instead of inflating a view with `onCreateView()`, you can pass a layout id to the superconstructor, and then create your binding by calling `bind` with the pre-existing view in `onCreateView()`.

```
class MyFragment: Fragment(R.layout.fragment_uhf_read) {

    private val arrayList: ArrayList<ReadUhfTagInfo?> = ArrayList()

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val binding = FragmentUhfReadBinding.bind(view)
        val listAdapter = ReadUhfTagInfoItemViewAdapter(this.context, arrayList)

        binding.lvData.adapter = listAdapter

        // ... other code using binding and listAdapter
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. First sentence explains what I have asked, and the rest explains what I have not asked about :) I have extra question: why `arrayList` in your example is not moved to onViewCreated scope?

Comment: I didn’t touch it because I don’t know what you’re doing with it. If it’s a list of stuff to show in your RecyclerView, it’s unusual that it appears in the Fragment at all instead of a ViewModel. But maybe it has simple constant data that you lazy-load and it doesn’t reference any context so there’s nothing to leak.

Comment: I see. Thank you. Well, I think I have to learn how to use Android ViewModels... I thought I will skip few new "technologies" when I started new project after several years of being divorced with Android, but looks like I have to dive into everything.